# Как получить список всех пользователей чата через Twitch.Lib

Tags: c#, asp.net, бот, twitch

хочу получить список всех пользователей чата через Twitch.lib, пробовал через `TwitchLib.Api.Core.Models.Undocumented`, но дальше не понял, что делать.
Пишу бота и хочу, добавить команду по типу. !поиск - выводит ник случайного пользователя  (не того кто написал команду и не ботов, ограничить пользователей и роли)

Comment: использую эту библиотеку https://github.com/TwitchLib/TwitchLib.Api

Comment: про функцию по желанию, если что ее сам допилю